# Regular expression match *abc* but not *bc*abc*bc*

Tags: regex, expression

I'm trying to find a regular expression to match all the combination of chars that have the string "question" but not have or contain the string "ion".

examples:

`questionxxxx ------> match`

`xxxquestion--------> match`

`questionxxxxion----> not match`

`xxxquestionxxx-----> match`

`xxxionxxxquestion--> not match`

I'm almost there but is missing me something!!!

this is what I have done:

`((?=.*question(?!.*ion.*).).*)|^question$`

This expression exclude all the strings with "ion" separated from "quest" but unfortunately also exclude "xxxquestion"

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: What about `questionquestion`?

Comment: none, just trying to find the correct expression in [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2v9bp)

Comment: `questionquestion` should be a match.

Comment: @user3049861: in this case you use a PCRE (perl compatible regular expression) engine. Will you use it with PHP later?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, my pattern does work with php if thats what you were going to get at.

Comment: @OGHaza: no, it was about my first pattern which does not work with javascript or java, since conditionals are not implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea how general you needed this solution to be, but the following works for your example:

```
(?!.*(?<!quest)ion)^.*question.*$
```

[RegExr Example](http://regexr.com?37eac)

Answer (score 0):

With perl compatible regex you can use this:

```
^(?:(question)|[^i]+|i(?!on))+(?(1)|(?!))$
```

With other regex flavors you can use this:

```
^(?:[^qi]+|q(?!uestion)|i(?!on))*question(?:[^i]+|i(?!on))*$
```